# Problema con tabla pivot en laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo un proyecto para la universidad y tengo un problema al trabajar con una tabla pivote, es la relación entre Vacunas (Vaccine) y Mascotas (Pet), es una relación de muchos a mucho, cree las migraciones tanto de Vaccine como de Pet, y de la tabla pivote pets_vaccines. Cree los modelos y sus relaciones pero cuando trato de ocupar la relacion no funciona. Ademas en la tabla pets_vaccines tengo 2 datos (scheduled_date y application_date) que necesito ocupar.

Mi idea es tener una vista donde muestre todos los datos de esa tabla pivote usando Eloquent, pero no puedo ni ingresar a los datos de la tabla pivote ni a los datos de otra tabla de la relación (es decir, si ocupo pets no puedo acceder a los datos de vaccine y viceversa).

Dejare los códigos de todo lo que ocupo para esto:

Modelo Vaccine

```
public function pets(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pets');
}
```

Modelo Pet

```
public function vaccines(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Vaccine')->withPivot('scheduled_date');
}
```

VaccineController

```
public function schedule()
    {
        $pets = Pet::get();

        return view('Vaccines.schedule', compact('pets'));
    }
```

Migration Pet

```
Schema::create('pets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->date('birthdate');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->date('castration_date');
        $table->string('weight');
        $table->string('picture')->nullable();


        //Foreign Keys

        $table->unsignedInteger('breed_id');
        $table->foreign('breed_id')->references('id')->on('breeds');

        $table->unsignedInteger('gender_id');
        $table->foreign('gender_id')->references('id')->on('genders');

        $table->unsignedInteger('type_id');
        $table->foreign('type_id')->references('id')->on('types');

        $table->unsignedInteger('food_id');
        $table->foreign('food_id')->references('id')->on('foods');

        $table->unsignedInteger('client_id');
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');

        $table->softDeletes();


        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Migration Vaccine

```
Schema::create('vaccines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Migration pets_vaccine

```
Schema::create('pets_vaccines', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->date('scheduled_date')->nullable();
        $table->date('application_date')->nullable();


        //Foreign Keys

        $table->unsignedInteger('vaccine_id');
        $table->foreign('vaccine_id')->references('id')->on('vaccines');

        $table->unsignedInteger('pet_id');
        $table->foreign('pet_id')->references('id')->on('pets');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y en la vista tengo esto:

```
 @foreach ($pets as $pet)
    Mascota: {{$pet->name}}  Vacuna: {{$pet->pivot->scheduled_date}} <br>
 @endforeach
```

Aqui, me da error el "scheduled_date", pero si lo quito me deja de dar el error pero no muestra lo que quiero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que veo en el código, solo estás llamando al modelo pet únicamente, debes llamar la relación y probablemente iterar sobre ella para ver sus datos:

(Teniendo en cuenta que es muchos a muchos, en teoría podría haber más de un registro).

```
@foreach ($pets as $pet)
  Mascota: {{$pet->name}}

  Vacunas: 
  @foreach ($pets->vaccines as $vaccine)
    {{ $vaccines->pivot->scheduled_at }}
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Lo más probable es que necesites hacer Eager Loading, aunque depende de cómo esté diseñado o de la cantidad de información:

```
Pet::with('vaccines')->get();
```